# Make the ellipsis after the list of ignored or interesting tags more obvious

Tags: feature-request, design, usability, ignored-tags

It is tiny to the point of invisibility. I was trying to work out why adding tags to the ignored tags list was doing nothing and I clicked on it by accident and discovered I'd added one tag about 3 times and also why half the posts I was looking at were highlighted I couldn't see the tag in either the ignored or interesting list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Lovely picture!